# Angular-cli build with base-href also return programs folder when using git bash

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to build my angular project with the angular-cli in a MINGW64 docker box on a Windows 7 Pro machine.

In git bash, the command I am using is:

```
ng build --prod --base-href /appcontext/
```

What I am trying to do is to modify my current base tag with attribute `href="/"` to `href="/appcontext/"`

Instead I get as a result a base tag with `href="C:/Program Files/Git/appcontext/"`.

Anyone any idea?

Comment: you try to modify your current tag to what with the result of what?
and what u mean by tag?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue with git bash? Got the same problem here.

Comment: @MeMeMax no, no solution yet

Comment: @MeMeMax I posted a new solution, you might want to have a look...

Answer (score 15):

Late answer, but I faced with the similar problem and it occured that issue in MINGW (I tried to run `ng-serve` with `--base-href` parameter through GIT Bash on Windows 10). Solved just by running in Powershell instead of GIT Bash - base-href parameter is handled fine there.

Comment: Thanks! The answer using `&#x2f;` didn't work for me but switching over to powershell to run the build command worked just fine.

Comment: Thank you! Saved me as well. GIT BASH + ng serve --base-href  = ISSUES

Answer (score 9):

*TLDR:* Replace first `/` with `&#x2f;`.

---

#### The problem:

I also encountered this issue when using git-bash on Windows. The git-bash sees the last argument of your command

```
ng build --prod --base-href /directory/
```

as a *path relative to its binary folder*, and prepends the argument with that (it converts the "seems-to-be" relative path into an absolute path).

#### Official solution *(which does not work but can be fixed):*

I tried [the suggested method](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5606) of using a double slash at the beginning:

```
ng build --prod --base-href //directory/
```

This will not be replaced by git-bash, however, the resulting base tag effectively makes the browser to not only replace the base path of URLs, but also the hostname, which is the first part of that string. So if you serve your app on host `hostname`, you want the URL to be

```
http://hostname/directory/
```

but it just became

```
http://directory/
```

You can fix this by also hard-coding the hostname into the base argument:

```
ng build --prod --base-href //hostname/directory/
```

The problem here is that your build now assumes a fixed hostname. As I did not like that solution, I experimented a little bit further and found a nice alternative.

#### My solution *(which currently works but can break in future versions):*

I found a clever "hack": *Replace the first slash by an HTML entity.* The CLI tool puts that string untouched into the `href="..."`, and does not (double-)escape the ampersand (which it should, IMHO). A possible entity for the slash symbol is `&#x2f;`, so your command looks like:

```
ng build --prod --base-href &#x2f;directory/
```

This looks strange, but works:

```
<base href="&#x2f;directory/">
```

That is exactly "equivalent" (in the HTML/XML sense) to

```
<base href="/directory/">
```

Note that when the Angular developers decide to "fix" this non-escaped argument in the CLI tool, this hack may no longer work, as that would result in

```
<base href="&amp;#x2f;directory/">
```

which ends up making your URLs look like

```
http://hostname/&#x2f;directory/
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks.

Comment: after running this command (ng build --prod --base-href &#x2f;directory/) the base href tag was empty(href="") in my case.

Answer (score 6):

I found on [this website](https://www.bayramucuncu.com/gitbash-angular-build-base-href-sorunu/) a solution that works for me on Git bash:

```
ng build –base-href="//my-path\\" --prod
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the similar problem when I run this command in git bash.

```
ng b --prod=true --base-href "/my-href/"
```

I got always this wrong href:

```
<base href="C:/Program Files/Git/my-href/">
```

I got the correct behavior after running the same command but in CMD (also Powershell is good, Windows).I got the intendent result

```
<base href="/my-href/">
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL` environment variable to disable path mangling

```
export MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL=--base-href=
```

or alternatively set it at the beginning of the command

```
MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL=--base-href= ng build --base-href="/mypath/"
```

Path conversion can be selectively disabled. MSYS2 reads an environment variable called MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL. This is a ; delimited string each part of which is compared against the front part of each argument and if a match is found, that conversion is skipped. An example of a value for MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL that would inhibit path transformations of the 3 cases above is /switch;/sdcard;--root=.

(source: https://github.com/msys2/msys2/wiki/Porting)

Answer (score 0):

Put your dist published folder content inside physical path **"C:/Program Files/Git/my-href/"** and open index.html file and replace base path with **"/my-href/"**

Answer (score 0):

**THE** solution, for  Git Bash 4 Windows, is:

```
ng build --configuration production --base-href='//context\'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).