# Not allowed to load local resource -error on chrome, Angular app is not running after production build

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, web-deployment, ng-build

I am having a problem with the deployment of an angular app. It does not occur on another machine if deployed. My app is not running and it shows the following error on Chrome:

**Not allowed to load local resource**

[image: error showing in Chrome browser]

and in Mozilla:

**'src' attribute of  element is not a valid URI**

[image: error showing in Mozilla browser]

The thing is, it is working completely fine if deployed from other machines. So I am guessing the issue is with the versions of node or typescript or ng or whatsoever. I am new to server deployment and this kind of issue is new to me.

**I am using following command to generate the deployment folder:**

```
ng build --prod --base-href /candidate/
```

***Following is my version details:***

*Node version:* `v10.16.3`

*Application `typescirpt` version:* `Version 2.9.2`

*Globally installed typescript version on the machine:* `Version 3.6.3`

[image: version details]

I deleted `node modules` and `package-lock.json` file and run `npm install` before production build. I got no error and was successfully able to generate `dist` folder.

**The deployment folder works perfectly if it is deployed from machines which have upgraded or downgraded node version installed.**

I have found many suggestions regarding the error shown on the browser, tried upgrading the node global versions but there is no way around. I am quite unsure about what I am missing here. Any kind of heads up would be great in this situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After digging into deep I found out that the problem is not with the version rather with the base URL it is generating in index.html file after build.

**This issue occurs when using git-bash on Windows.**

The git-bash sees the last argument of the command- **`ng build --prod --base-href /candidate/`** as a path relative to its binary folder and prepends the argument with that (it converts the "seems-to-be" relative path into an absolute path).

**So, I used PowerShell instead of Git-Bash and the issue was gone.**  The base-href parameter is handled fine there.

To resolve the issue with git-bash go through [***this link***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292761/angular-cli-build-with-base-href-also-return-programs-folder-when-using-git-bash), which actually helped me to resolved my particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

**You should control base tag in index.html in dist folder.**

```
<base href="/">
```